# After a short while Visual Studio no longer accepts semicolon

Tags: visual-studio-2013

When I start up Visual Studio 2013 everything works perfectly, then after 10-20 minutes it stops allowing me to type semicolon but everything else sill works. I can copy/paste semicolons from elsewhere in the source file, but this is a real pain.

It has been doing this for a few days. I didn't manually update anything recently.

I tried clearing the Resharper cache and even disabled Resharper altogether just in case but the problem keeps on happening.

Help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally discovered what my problem is. I am writing a reusable library and want to build .Net 4.0 and .Net 4.5 versions from the same source code. I achieved this by creating two projects in the same folder that reference the same source files but are configured to target different frameworks, and use different bin and obj folders.

This setup seems to work really well for the most part, but it appears to really confuse the Visual Studio intellisense system because when you open a source file and edit it, Intellisense doesn't know whether to make suggestions from the .Net 4.0 or 4.5 framework because the source file belongs to both projects.

I solved my semicolon problem by unloading the .Net 4.5 project whilst editing and debugging the code, then reloading it when I want to make a release build.

Comment: How were you able to achieve this - `that reference the same source files but are configured to target different frameworks`? I create a project with few *.cs files. Then, I create the second project and try to add the existing files from first project. When I do this Visual Studio automatically copies all the selected files into local folder of my 2nd project. That means, there are now two physical copies of same file which got created in respective folders. So I'm curious how were you able to refer to same source code from two different projects targeting different .Net framework versions?

Comment: Also, I request you to please mark your post as an accepted answer if your problem is solved, so that community can focus on questions which are actually unsolved. Glad that you were able to help yourself.

Comment: I have to wait 24 hours before I can accept my own answer - 9 hours remaining

Comment: There are several ways to make two or more projects reference the same source files. One way is to choose "Add -> Existing Item" then in the file selection dialog instead of clicking the "Add" button, drop down the list right next to it and choose "Add As Link". This will add a reference to the existing file without copying it into your project folder.

Comment: Good to know that we can add links or shortcuts in place of real physical files as visual studio items. This is wow! I'm also thinking of another use case now where I would want to use them -> AssemblyInfo.cs files. Now I will keep all common assembly info attributes in a single project and will refer through links in all other projects. This way I will have to make a single change for info like productName, productVesion etc. while making a release/build.

Comment: @bikerman868 I was not aware of this 24 hour limit :) Is it for other's answers too or only when we answer our own question?

Comment: Yes, I almost always have projects in a solution sharing a file with version info so that all the DLLs from a build will have the same version number.

Comment: Only when you answer your own question. I think the restriction is there to stop people posting a bunch of questions and immediately answering them to game the reputation system.